# Factoring expression with rational powers

Tags: algebra, factorization

To any great *Mathematica*-matician. Why *Mathematica* can’t factor this

```
Factor[-1+x^(2/3)]
```

I know that `Factor` mainly targets polynomials but in the "Generalization" section of the help page, there is a quite similar example:

```
Factor[x^(2/3 s) + 2 x^s + 1]
(* (1 + x^(s/3)) (1 - x^(s/3) + 2 x^(2 s/3)) *)
```

I would expect it to handle my case as well and that it gives a result like this one:

```
(x^(1/3)-1)*(x^(1/3)+1)
```

Comment: What result would you expect from it?

Comment: It's not quite clear what result you expect as this is not a polynomial. `Factor` works with polynomials.

Comment: Wow, so quick. I will study this answer. I think is fine. Thank you Akku14.

Comment: Why is the expected result not `(x^(1/6)-1)*(x^(1/6)+1)*(x^(1/3)+1)`?

Comment: I will vote to close this because it a simple mistake. The wrong assumption you made is that your function is a polynomial in `x` which it is not: `PolynomialQ[-1 + x^(2/3), x]`. The reference page of `Factor` clearly says that it factors polynomials. With @Akku's answer you have a good start to dig deeper but in its current form, the question makes no sense.

Comment: @halirutan @Szabolcs Your statements are not fully correct. In the documentation on `Factor` in the `Generalizations and extensions` section it is written that "Some non-polynomial expressions can be factored" and an example very similar to this one is given ! Whether this was originally a design feature, or rather a undesired side effect is another story, but it is in the documentation. Thus, the question is legitimate.

Comment: @yarchik That is indeed a fair point and I haven't seen this example! However, the headline of the question says "polynomial" and the OP seemed to have missed the point that (a) it is not a polynomial and (b) that `Factor` *in general* was made for polynomials. I'm going to edit the question to improve it.

Comment: @halirutan Fair enough !

Comment: The GCD of 2 and 3 is 1. For this reason, the code that attempts to convert an expression into a "polynomial" (in some set of variables) determines that `x^(2/3 s) + 2 x^s + 1` should be rewritten as a cubic polynomial in `x^(1/3)`. In contrast, `-1+x^(2/3)` is already a linear polynomial in `x^(2/3)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about that

```
-1 + x^(2/3) // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
             FullSimplify // Factor // PowerExpand

(*   (-1 + x^(1/3)) (1 + x^(1/3))   *)
```

Comment: Surprisingly your method also works even for very large rational exponents such as `128/173`